# The abstract concept name of symbol `%`

Tags: python

This might be frivolous, but what's the symbol `%` as an abstract concept name?   For example, `\` is called "escape symbol" in addition to "backslash", while `%` is just called "percent symbol",

```
In [45]: content = "percent and format me"
In [46]: print("test %s" % content)
test percent and format me
```

Is it named "formatted symbol"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analagously to `\` serving the function of an "escape character" `%` can be one of:

1. **Remainder** or **Modulo operator**. It is implemented through the [`__mod__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__mod__) special function (and can be invoked by the [`mod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mod) operator). From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations):

   > The `%` (modulo) operator yields the remainder from the division of the first argument by the second...
2. **Interpolation operator** or **formatting operator**. This is a special implementation of the modulo operator for strings and string-like objects. The operation it performs has nothing to do with integer division, but aside from that, it's just a regular binary operator. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting):

   > String objects have one unique built-in operation: the `%` operator (modulo). This is also known as the string *formatting* or *interpolation* operator.

   [and](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-bytes-formatting):

   > Bytes objects (`bytes`/`bytearray`) have one unique built-in operation: the `%` operator (modulo). This is also known as the bytes *formatting* or *interpolation* operator.

Comment: God,I'm done. "Interpolation operator", I'm thinking of such a name for months.

Comment: Technically, interpolation is a special implementation of the modulo operator for strings. I always thought it was a bit counter-intuitive, but you get used to it.

Comment: You can `"test %s".__mod__("percent and format me")` if you want to.

Answer (score 3):

String formatting operator, or interpolation operator: https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/typesseq-strings.html